# Error con URL al hacer paginación

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de crear una paginación, pero al momento en que intento paginar, me indica error el explorador de

> objeto no localizado

Estoy tratando de crear la paginación con PHP 7 y su MVC. Sí me trae el conte de la paginación o mejor dicho el número de páginas que existen, pero al momento que quiero navegar entre ellas, me arroja el error.

Hice lo que son las URLs de lista blanca y creo que desde ahí es donde viene el problema,

```
$rutas = array();
    $infoVacante = null;

    if (isset($_GET["ruta"])) {
        $rutas = explode("/", $_GET["ruta"]);

        $item = "titulo";
        $valor =$rutas[0];

        $rutaVacante = ControladorVacantes::ctrmMostrarRuta($item, $valor);
        if ($rutas[0] == $rutaVacante["titulo"]) {
            $infoVacante = $rutas[0];
        }

        if ($infoVacante != null){
            include 'modulos/infovacante.php';
        } else if(
            $rutas[0] == "verificar" ||
            $rutas[0] == "vacantes" ||
            $rutas[0] == "alertas" ||
            $rutas[0] == "notificaciones" ||
            $rutas[0] == "cambiar-contrasena" ||
            $rutas[0] == "nosotros" ||
            $rutas[0] == "contacto" ||
            $rutas[0] == "terminos" ||
            $rutas[0] == "info" ||
            $rutas[0] == "salir") {
            include 'modulos/'. $rutas[0] .'.php';
        } else {
            include 'modulos/error404.php';
        }
    }
```

Así es como llamo las publicaciones y mando a llamar el listado para generarle el conteo:

```
<?php

if(isset($rutas[1])){
  $base = ($rutas[1] - 1) * 2;
  $tope = 1;
} else{
  $rutas[1] = 1;
  $base = 0;
  $tope = 1;
  $modo = "DESC";
}

$ordenar = "id";

$vacantes = ControladorVacantes::ctrMostrarVacantes($ordenar, $base, $tope, $modo);
$listarVacantes = ControladorVacantes::ctrListarVacantes($ordenar);
```

Y así es como genero la paginación:

```
if(count($listarVacantes) != 0){

    $paginacionProductos = ceil(count($listarVacantes)/1);

    if($paginacionProductos > 4){

      if($rutas[1] == 1){

        echo '<ul class="pagination">';             
        for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i ++){
          echo '<li id="item'.$i.'"><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }

        echo ' <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>
             <li id="item'.$paginacionProductos.'"><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.$paginacionProductos.'">'.$paginacionProductos.'</a></li>
             <li><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/2"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        </ul>';

      } else if($rutas[1] != $paginacionProductos && 
            $rutas[1] != 1 &&
            $rutas[1] <  ($paginacionProductos/2) &&
            $rutas[1] < ($paginacionProductos-3)) {

          $numeroPagActual = $rutas[1];

          echo '<ul class="pagination">
              <li><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.($numeroPagActual-1).'"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li> ';

          for($i = $numeroPagActual; $i <= ($numeroPagActual+3); $i ++){

            echo '<li id="item'.$i.'"><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';

          }

          echo ' <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>
               <li id="item'.$paginacionProductos.'"><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.$paginacionProductos.'">'.$paginacionProductos.'</a></li>
               <li><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.($numeroPagActual+1).'"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>

          </ul>';

      } else if($rutas[1] != $paginacionProductos && 
            $rutas[1] != 1 &&
            $rutas[1] >=  ($paginacionProductos/2) &&
            $rutas[1] < ($paginacionProductos-3)) {

          $numeroPagActual = $rutas[1];

          echo '<ul class="pagination">
             <li><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.($numeroPagActual-1).'"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li> 
             <li id="item1"><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/1">1</a></li>
             <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>
          ';

          for($i = $numeroPagActual; $i <= ($numeroPagActual+3); $i ++){

            echo '<li id="item'.$i.'"><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';

          }


          echo '  <li><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.($numeroPagActual+1).'"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>';
      } else {

        $numPagActual = $rutas[1];

        echo '<ul class="pagination">
             <li><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.($numPagActual-1).'"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li> 
             <li id="item1"><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/1">1</a></li>
             <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>
          ';

        for($i = ($paginacionProductos-3); $i <= $paginacionProductos; $i ++){

          echo '<li id="item'.$i.'"><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';

        }

        echo ' </ul>';

      }

    } else {

      echo '<ul class="pagination">';

      for($i = 1; $i <= $paginacionProductos; $i ++){

        echo '<li id="item'.$i.'"><a href="'.$url.$rutas[0].'/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';

      }

      echo '</ul>';

    }
  }

?>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en mi .htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

> Edición de archivo .htaccess

```
# Impedir que se pueda ver el listado de contenidos de un directorio

Options All -Indexes

# Url Amigables

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

Como se puede notar en el `RewriteRule` se le ha añadido un `/` con el que me ha aceptado la paginación, pero el problem es que al navegar en la paginacion comienza a eliminar variables como la siguiente, donde le añado el tipo de modo en que debe aparecer las publicaciones refiriendome a `"DESC" o "ASC"`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al momento de querer regresar a la pagina de "vacantes" la url se queda de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo obtienes `$_GET["ruta"]`? Me imagino que tienes definidas redirecciones en .htaccess o a través de algún controlador, ¿podrías compartirlas? Porque me imagino que el problema va a estar por ahí (combinado con las lista blanca que mencionas).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro una disculpa por no haber respondido, me quede sin computadora el fin de semana, pero ya pude actualizar mi pregunta con los cambios que realice, desde la actualizacion de las rutas y adicione lo que tengo en el htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo tu problema está en estas dos líneas:

```
    $ruta = null;
```

y

```
if ($ruta != null ||
```

como en ningún momento le asignás a $ruta otro valor esa expresión siempre da false, ejecutando siempre el código:

```
    include 'modulos/error404.php';
```

---

Por lo que veo ahora el problema está entonces con el .htaccess, no está capturando correctamente el request. Te convendría reemplazarlo por algo como esto:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Que verifica si el archivo o directorio no existe y entonces si redirige la petición al index.php

Para poder capturar la ruta pedida lo podés hacer a través de la variable:

```
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Espero que eso te oriente mejor.

---

Si por comodidad prefieres seguir tomando el request en $_GET['ruta'], cambia la última línea del .htaccess por:

```
    RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?ruta=$1 [R]
```

---

El error que te tira se da porque cuando entras a '/vacantes/2', este if da true

```
    if(isset($rutas[1])){
```

y ejecuta este código:

```
  $base = ($rutas[1] - 1) * 2;
  $tope = 1;
```

es decir, nunca declara la variable $modo. Tendrías que revisar si la condición que pusiste es la que necesitás.

Comment: una disculpa por no haber respondido, me quede sin computadora el fin de semana, pero ya pude actualizar mi pregunta con los cambios que realice, desde la actualizacion de las rutas y adicione lo que tengo en el htaccess

Comment: al `RewriteRule` del htacces me falto añadirle un / al final y ahora funciona, pero al momento que hago la paginacion el valor 0 del array no se quita, y aparece como `localhos/nombreDeLaCarpeta/ruta/ruta` o `localhos/nombreDeLaCarpeta/ruta/ruta2`

Comment: No estoy seguro de entender el cambio que hiciste. ¿Puedes modificar la pregunta y agregar los cambios? Gracias!

Comment: Listo, he actualizado la pregunta

Comment: Ahí agregué la respuesta a tu última pregunta.